# What the overhead of Java ORM for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, morphia, spring-data

What is the overhead of using Java ORM for MongoDB, or its better that we go the at basic driver level to read or write?

We will be adding Mongo DB for one of our requirements.

There are couple of java ORM mapping tools for java 
-morphia 
-spring-data 
-[others](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center)

Morphia last version was released more than a year ago 
but Spring data is actively maintained.
Which one should be used if I am about to start now,

Comment: Doesn't the "R" in ORM stand for "relational"?

Comment: Yes, its stand for Object/Relational Mapping, typically used with relational databases but generically can be used with any type of database.

Comment: @duffymo in this case Morphia actually *does* map relations between collections. A few of the Ruby wrappers have similar features.

Comment: OK, thanks to all.  I immediately assumed relational meant SQL.

Comment: Spring-data uses morphia in order to access MongoDB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using ORM decreases the performance but it speed up the development. There is a trade off here.

For ORM tools, Morphia is most stable one. [Here](http://www.scalabiliti.com/blog/mongodb_and_morphia_performance) you can find the comparison between the Morphia and Basic Mongo Driver by their performance.

Answer (score 4):

Morphia seems to be best suitable as it has the most features and have active community. See this link for comparison: [How do Morphia, Mongo4j and Spring data for MongoDB compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837135/how-do-morphia-mongo4j-and-spring-data-for-mongodb-compare)

Answer (score 4):

There's quite a few thing's to mention here in general. Coming up with benchmarks for that is quite hard as you cannot really test the performance without testing your MongoDB setup as well. Thus one can pretty much can tweak and tune ones environment to deliver the results wanted.

Beyond that you have to distinguish between read and write performance. Especially writes are heavily influenced by the `WriteConcern` used. Thus, what might be an overhead of 50% in a `WriteConcern.NONE` scenario can easily turn down to less than 5% with a `WriteConcern.SAFE`.

Yes, there definitely is an overhead in any ODM implementation as the Object <-> `DBObject` mapping has to inspect the object get and set values usually via reflection. Thus a crucial point IMHO is the ability to plug in custom manually coded converters that you might want to provide for the performance critical objects. For Spring Data simply registering a custom `EntityInstantiator` that does `new Person(…)` instead of letting the default one do its reflection magic gives a huge boost in performance.

The Spring Data team has a [build](https://build.springsource.org/browse/SPRINGDATA-MONGODBPERF) set up a build weighting performance of a OTS MongoDB instance for writes against different `WriteConcern`s, and reading through the plain driver, the `MongoTemplate` and the repositories abstraction. The numbers are to be taken with a grain of salt as they sometimes show the repositories reading data faster than the templates which *has* to be influenced by the infrastructure by some means as it's pretty much a layer on top of the template but doesn't really add any caching.

Comment: Do you think spring data can be more faster than morphia?

Comment: Of course it can. But of course Morphia can also be faster than Spring Data. I think the crucial point is - as outline above - in how far you are able to manually code the Object to DBObject mapping for types that turn out to be bottle necks to prevent the generic mapping infrastructure influence performance too much. If you're stuck with a mapping approach not being customizable, that's bad.