# Exporting data obtained by Parsing XML to MongoDB

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, jdbc

I have parsed data from XML using JDOM Parser and got my data into discrete fields.

I want to export that data  as well as  complete XML Files to MongoDB.

So in a way I want something similar to JDBC for MongoDB.

Kindly advise me.

Comment: Similar questions have been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837135/how-do-morphia-mongo4j-and-spring-data-for-mongodb-compare/5933258).  There are a number of different [Object Mapping tools](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center#JavaLanguageCenter-ThirdPartyFrameworksandLibs) available for MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stennie.I went through the ORM's but according to you what would be the ORM to use to Integrate SpringMVC Application with MongoDB,whether it would be Morphia/Java Mongo Driver or can Hibernate work with MongoDB.

Comment: Choice really depends on your preferences .. [Spring Data for MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/) is probably the closest fit, but you could use any of the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stennie for your response.It helped a lot.