# MongoDB Schema Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, schema

I am aware that MongoDB doesn't have a Schema. I have looked on the Internet but can't find anything.

Basically there is a API for Java Spring MongoDB. Is there any way to define a schema for MongoDB on top of Spring so the Schema can be controlled. I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at both [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) and [Spring Data MongoDB](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/).  Both of them are libraries that help you interact with MongoDB.

Here is a [comparison between Morphia, Mongo4j, and Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837135/how-do-morphia-mongo4j-and-spring-data-for-mongodb-compare).